# gawk: change 5th element on every other line

Tags: printing, awk, line, gawk

I want to add a line break (\n) in front of the 5th element on every other line:

```
2, 0, 0, 0, 2
4, 0, 0, 0, 4
6, 0, 0, 0, 6
8, 0, 0, 0, 8
```

... in order to get:

```
2, 0, 0, 0, 2
4, 0, 0, 0, \n4
6, 0, 0, 0, 6
8, 0, 0, 0, \n8
```

What I have so far in gawk doesn't work:

```
gawk '{if (NR % 2) {$5=\n$5; print} else print}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say:

```
awk '{NR%2 || $5="\\n"$5 }1' filename
```

Note that you'll need to escape the `\` in order to get a literal `\`.

For your input, it'd produce:

```
2, 0, 0, 0, 2
4, 0, 0, 0, \n4
6, 0, 0, 0, 6
8, 0, 0, 0, \n8
```

Alternatively, (as pointed out by [@WilliamPursell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140750/william-pursell)), you could say:

```
awk '!(NR%2) {$5="\\n"$5 }1' filename
```

Comment: Using a short circuiting `||` here is a bit obscure.  It seems more idiomatic to write `awk '!(NR%2){$5="\\n"$5}1'`

Comment: @WilliamPursell thanks, updated as per your suggestion.